# Loading Files from a Named External Stage vs External Location

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have our data files as JSON on GCP Cloud Storage.

Which of the below 2 approach is the ideal/efficient way to load it to snowflake existing table

1. Use GCS as Named External Stage
2. Use GCS as External Location to load data

If (1), then should we go for [Calling Snowpipe REST Endpoints to Load Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest.html#calling-snowpipe-rest-endpoints-to-load-data) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "efficiency" is pretty much the same for either method, but I'd strongly recommend going the route of Auto Ingest Snowpipe, as outlined in this link:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-gcs.html

This works really well and allows for a "set it and forget it" type of project.

Comment: Word of caution: Snowpipe is still a preview feature on GCP

Comment: Exactly, for GCP SnowPipe Auto Ingest is in Preview. So I would rather resort to not use it for my Production purpose.